# Windows 8.1 fails to upgrade MigHost.exe Error: WdsInitialize failed to initialize

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1-upgrade

I am currently running Windows 8 and get the following error message around 70 - 73% after the gathering info stage of upgrading to 8.1. I have no applications running and have tried several reboots. There doesn't appear to be an error code and not much on Google. Does anyone know what I can try without reinstalling Windows 8 or somewhere I can look at a log for more information? C: drive has 217 GB free (I have heard low disk space can be a problem)

It's one of those error messages, that you keep clicking OK to but it keeps coming back. I just end up restarting and then it only shows again when I try and do the update again.

**Update**

Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x800704C7: English (United Kingdom) ESD Bundle Parent.

[image: Error message]

[image: Spec]

Comment: First step use DISM to verify there isn't any system corruption.

Comment: @Ramhound Could you expand on how I use DISM or even how I get hold of it?

Comment: Its a system tool that already exists on your system.  (Eight Forums)[www.eightforums.com] has a nice tutorial on how to use the tool.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx also upload the log files: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824819.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 Looking in the System log, the only error is the one I have put in my update, slightly different error code "Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x800704C7: English (United Kingdom) ESD Bundle Parent."

Comment: 0x800704C7 = ERROR_CANCELLED (The operation was canceled by the user). So you canceled the setup.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I believe that was just another error I found so it probably came after.

Comment: Has anyone get any advice on this?